# Scikit-Learn issues error for RandomForestClassifier for multilabel classification - Jagged arrays

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, random-forest, multilabel-classification

Scikit-Learn RandomForestClassifier throws an error for a multilabel classification problem.

1. This code creates a RandomForestClassifier multilabel object, given predictors `C` and multi-labels `out` with no error.

```
C = np.array([[2,4,6],[4,2,1],[8,3,1]])
out = np.array([[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]])
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=True)
rf.fit(C,out)
```

2. If I modify the multilabels, so that all the elements at a certain index are the same, say (where all the first components of the multilabels equals zero)

```
out = np.array([[0,1],[0,1],[0,0]])
```

I get an error and traceback:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a 
list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. 
If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  y_pred = np.array(y_pred, copy=False)

raise ValueError(
    507             "The type of target cannot be used to compute OOB "
    508             f"estimates. Got {y_type} while only the following are "
    509             "supported: continuous, continuous-multioutput, binary, "
    510             "multiclass, multilabel-indicator."
    511         )
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2,)
```

3. Not requesting OOB predictions does not result in an error:

```
rf_err = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=False)
```

I cannot figure out why keeping the OOB predictions would trigger such an error, when all the n-component of a multilabel are equal.

Answer (score 1):

In your setup `out_err = np.array([[0,1],[0,1],[0,0]])` you do not have any examples of the second class, so you only have elements of 1 class.

That means that there is no 'class label' dimension and it can be omitted. That's why you see `(2,)` shape.

Please, describe your initial intent: why would you need to set a particular position in labels to 0. If you try to go with `N-1` classes instead of `N` classes  I suggest removing the position itself and the elements of the class from the dataset, not putting all zeros:

```
out=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]  # 3 classes
# remove the second class:
out=[[1,0],[0,1],[1,0]]  # 2 classes
```

Comment: thank you. Yes it is a clumsy example and i could remove the column. But 1) why does it run with `oob=false ` not with `oob= true ` ? If your explanation were correct, it should not make a difference. Please note it was working well.with `Numpy =< 1.20`.

Comment: I am also not sure I follow your terminology. In a multilabel setting I have 2 classes, {O,1}, and I want a 2-label classifier. The fact that all the classes are the same for say the first label might not carry usefyl information, but why should it yield an error. Withiut saving out-of-bag results, there is no error anyhow!

Comment: Could you describe - what you wanted to achieve by the modification in the first place? Some practical case or is it a purely theoretical question?

Comment: It is a purely theoretical question, actually coming from a mistake i mafe in pre-processing data, resulting in the first column of the labels to be all zerosm It was running ok (ultimatrly, no harm is done by adding null informartion). Then after updating numpy, the error popped up.

Comment: if a practical setting could be of any use, please consider this hypothetical one. I have got n users, described by k predictors. Need to classify them in multiclass fashion. Do they like pop music (0,1) ?Do they like baroque music? (0,1)? Do they like techno-trance (0,1)? Hence, three labels per user. Now after running this model, they tell me to add another clasdto my multilabel, "do the user like etno-folk?". Ok doable, but it just turns out all the users in my training set do not like it, so a certain column on the multilabel is all zeros. This should NOT result in an error.

Comment: Sounds logical. I'll have a look and reproduce it and return later (day or two).